# Why doesn't Rails use the correct version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Ruby 2.0 installed but Rails doesn't recognize it and tells me to upgrade to 1.9.3.

When I run:

```
rails console
```

I get:

```
Rails 4 prefers to run on Ruby 2.0.

You're running
  ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Please upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 or newer to continue.
```

This happens with all Rails commands. `rails new`, `rails s`, etc., however, I definitely have Ruby 2.0 installed:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

It also doesn't seem to be a problem with an incorrect default version of Ruby:

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

ruby-1.9.3-p429 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I read somewhere that it might be a problem with my PATH variable:

```
printenv PATH
/Users/Aoeu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Aoeu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0- p195@global/bin:/Users/Aoeu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/Aoeu/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

My Ruby seems to be installed in the right place:

```
which ruby
/Users/Aoeu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does it use the correct version when you start the console like this: `bundle exec rails c`?

Comment: It tells me "Could not locate Gemfile" but rails isn't letting me create a new project. "rails new" fails, telling me that I need to upgrade to 1.9.3

Comment: If you install RVM with the `--auto-dotfiles` and `--autolibs=enabled` options, it takes care of PATH and dependencies for you.

Comment: What’s the output of `which rails`?

Comment: "which rails" returns "/Users/Aoeu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/rails"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like something got really messed up in your rvm configuration. In [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4414441), the OP solved it by uninstalling rvm and reinstalling everything from scratch.

Be sure to enable autolibs by running:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=homebrew --rails
```

Comment: Yay. SUCCESS! Reinstalled ruby and rails with autolibs on. Now, everything works!

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your gem environment which version of Ruby to use.  You can do this in the command line with:

```
rvm --default 2.0.0
```

Comment: This worked for me, even knowing it was displaying it already was the default.